# julia inf by inf different results

Tags: julia

I'm quite new to Julia - version 1.0.0 on Windows. The [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/integers-and-floating-point-numbers/) states the following

```
julia> Inf / Inf
NaN
```

But when I perform the following I'm getting different results

```
julia> 1/0
Inf

julia> 1/0 / 1/0  # this should be NaN right, tried (1/0)/(1/0) as well
Inf

julia> 1/0
Inf

julia> ans/ans
NaN
```

Why `1/0 / 1/0` is not `NaN`, whereas `ans/ans` is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You actually have:

```
julia> (1/0)/(1/0)
NaN
```

so this is consistent.

Now regarding:

```
julia> 1/0 / 1/0
Inf
```

Please observe how it is evaluated:

```
julia> :(1/0 / 1/0)
:(((1 / 0) / 1) / 0)
```

so we get a standard left to right evaluation (as should be expected). And you get:

```
julia> 1/0
Inf

julia> (1/0)/1
Inf

julia> ((1/0)/1)/0
Inf
```

And all is OK.

Actually here you have one special thing to observe (this is not directly related to your question but is good to know as it might come up as a next question):

```
julia> Inf / 0
Inf

julia> Inf / (-0)
Inf

julia> Inf / (0.0)
Inf

julia> Inf / (-0.0)
-Inf
```

The reason is that integer `0` is the same as `-0`:

```
julia> 0 === -0
true
```

but floats carry sign bit:

```
julia> 0.0 === -0.0
false
```